# How to implement feature extraction in Julia

Tags: machine-learning, julia, feature-extraction

I am trying to make a binary classifier using machine learning and I am trying to develop other features for my data using correlated features (numerical attributes) I have. I searched much but could not get a block of code that will work with me.
What should i do?

I've searched in dimenshionality reduction and found library (Multivariate Statistics) but actually i did not understand and i felt lost :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one will make a choice for you what exact method to choose. They are many, many different ways of doing a binary classification and to do feature extraction. If you feel overwhelmed by all these names that libraries such as Multivariate Statistics offer, then take a look at a textbook on statistics and machine learning, understanding the methods is independent from the programming language.

Start with some simple methods such as principal compenent analysis (PCA), (MultivariateStats.jl provides that), then test others as you gain more knowledge on your data and the methods.

Some Julia libraries to take a look at: JuliaStats (https://github.com/JuliaStats) with its parts

- StatsBase for the most basic stuff
- MultivariateStats for methods like PCA
- StatsModels (and DataFrames) for statistical models
- many more ....

For Neural Networks there are Flux.jl and KNet.jl

For Clustering there is Clustering.jl

Then, there are also bindings to the python libraries Tensorflow (Neural Networks & more) and Scikit-Learn (all kinds of ML algorithms)

There are many more projects, but these are some that I think are important.